# AES256 encryption, output characters depending on input... why?

Tags: c#, encryption, encoding, aes

I'm using VS to encrypt some data using this function:

```
public static byte[] AES_Encrypt(byte[] bytesToBeEncrypted, byte[] passwordBytes)
{
    byte[] encryptedBytes = null;

    // Set your salt here, change it to meet your flavor:
    // The salt bytes must be at least 8 bytes.
    byte[] saltBytes = new byte[] { 6, 99, 26, 12, 68, 22, 89, 12, 49, 55, 92, 82, 87, 86, 10, 75, 98, 122, 73 };

    using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
    {
        using (RijndaelManaged AES = new RijndaelManaged())
        {
            AES.KeySize = 256;
            AES.BlockSize = 256;

            var key = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(passwordBytes, saltBytes, 1000);
            AES.Key = key.GetBytes(AES.KeySize / 8);
            AES.IV = key.GetBytes(AES.BlockSize / 8);

            AES.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;

            using (var cs = new CryptoStream(ms, AES.CreateEncryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Write))
            {
                cs.Write(bytesToBeEncrypted, 0, bytesToBeEncrypted.Length);
                cs.Close();
            }
            encryptedBytes = ms.ToArray();
        }
    }

    return encryptedBytes;
}
```

My question is why when I put plain text to encrypt the output only contains readable characters that can be viewed with any text processor like notepad, but, if the data to encrypt is from a file containing special characters the output now also contains special characters that can't be viewed from text processor... why???

Example of encrypt "hello"
"fMIiLZzIKME2gTAarpQqP7y8kOjQvDS12lSOOBtaCbI="

Example of encrypt binary data:
"b!,˜à4ovƒº1úlÔÊ jô†õ   ;>²Ñ)j¦¹‘åüLÖN—nU+5"

Comment: Please remove "Cypher" from the tags. This tag is related to [Cypher Query Language](https://neo4j.com/developer/cypher-query-language/).

Answer (score 0):

Because AES doens't deal with chars, or strings, only with bytes.

If you do want to be able to look at the result in a text editor, you'll have to encode the outputted bytes.

One of such encoders would be the [base64](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dhx0d524(v=vs.110).aspx) one.

Which would output a human "readable" string.

Comment: Yes, I know AES only see bytes... but is really rare that the output contains non readable characters only if the input containt it too... don't you think?

Comment: I would've called coincidence on that one, but then there was your self answer :)

Answer (score 0):

I found the probem... I'm an idiot... I have a Convert.ToBase64String function called when the input is plain text... I didn't see this.

Sorry.

Thans